# Using godrb with delayed_job pools

Tags: ruby, delayed-job, god

I want to start a delayed_job using multiple pools (4) each pool can take a certain type of jobs and one last for everything (in order to prioritize quick tasks and let longer run on separate pools).

This is the command ran :

```
/bin/bash -c 'cd /usr/src/app; /usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=development /usr/src/app/bin/delayed_job --pool=LongTask,MediumTask:2 --pool=QuickTask --pool=*:1 start'
```

I would like to monitor this with god, but how can I monitor forked processes with godrb ? I would like to keep the process generatin in the delayed_jobs if possible, instead of running 4 god instances each with one delayed_jobs pool.